# Preserve leading zeros SQL

Tags: sql, database

I am saving a number eg. 000001 in a SQL TEXT field which causes the leading zeros to be lost.

I need the TEXT type field as the data may contain letters and/or numbers.

Any suggestions how I could preserve the leading zeros while still storing the data in a TEXT type field?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Is it SQLite?

Comment: Are you sure your query insert a string and not an integer?

Comment: How are you saving the number?  Presumably not as `INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES('000001')`, so how?

Comment: This is offtopic, but assuming you're trying to create some unique ID, you shouldn't be using `TEXT`, but rather `VARCHAR`.

Comment: To clarify: I'm using SQLite, the number is inserted from a var containing the number and the data is not unique.

Comment: VTC as NARQ since OP has stated in comments to the answer it's an `INT` not `TEXT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `0000001` is not a number. It is a string. Are you trying to store a number 1 in a text field, or are you trying to store the string `'0000001'` in a text field? I assume the problem is that you are doing th former.

If you believe you are not doing that, show us your code.

Comment: Storing the string '000001' is indeed what I want and I have realized that I had the data type of the field set to INTEGER not TEXT.  Thanks for trying to help, now how do I close this before I look **more** silly...

Comment: @ThunderHorse: accept the answer you've been given.  People will then let the question go quietly into oblivion.

Comment: I use the following rule, it could prove useful to you in future situation. Unless a field is expected to be used for calculation ,i always store it as a text.Especially if it's not automatically generated.